# How to tell if a setInterval is the last thing that's stopping an app from exiting

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to know how many tasks node has to finish before the process will automatically exit because there is nothing else to do? I want to use `setInterval` but only while the app is busy. I don't want to prevent the process to auto fire the exit event:

```
// an app that does serveral things, then finishes

// this should only be active whilst the app is busy:
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    // some stuff

    // how to determine if the interval is the last thing to complete?
    if(process.lastThingToDo == interval)
        clearInterval(interval);
}, 2500);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a timer that will still work like a normal timer, but will not stop the process from exiting, you can use `.unref()` on it.

```
// an app that does serveral things, then finishes

// this should only be active whilst the app is busy:
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    // some stuff

    // how to determine if the interval is the last thing to complete?
    if(process.lastThingToDo == interval)
        clearInterval(interval);
}, 2500);

// add this .unref() call to make it so the process will not wait for this timer
// before exiting, but the timer will otherwise work normally
interval.unref();
```

See the [node.js doc for `.unref()`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_unref) with timers.